# Java get String from subclass

Tags: java, class

Imagine I have this:

```
public class Animal {
    private String racaAnimal;
    private String corAnimal;

    public String getCorAnimal() {
        return this.corAnimal;
    }

    public String getRacaAnimal() {
        return this.racaAnimal;
    } 

            public Animal getAnimaisCliente(int indice) {
                    return this.animaisCliente[indice];
            }  
}

public class Estimacao extends Animal{
    private String nomeAnimal;

    public String getNomeAnimal() {
        return nomeAnimal;
    }
}

public class Cliente{
    private Animal[] animaisCliente;
}
```

Constructors aren't showing but they are working fine.

I have one arraylist that holds all Cliente

```
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
```

And a animal is created like this

```
Estimacao animaisEstimacao = new Estimacao(nomeAnimal,racaAnimal,corAnimal);
```

and then its added to the array of Animal in Cliente

Now if I do this:

```
System.out.println(" Raça: " + clientes.get(0).getAnimaisCliente(0).getRacaAnimal());
```

It works.
But how can i get nomeAnimal from class Estimacao?

If i put

```
System.out.println(" Nome: " + clientes.get(0).getAnimaisCliente(0).getNomeAnimal());
```

it do not works.

From a subclass we can get things from the super class but the other way arroud? is it possible?

Comment: I am not fully understanding the question, but I am guessing that an abstract method would meet requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(" Nome: " + ((Estimacao) clientes.get(0).getAnimaisCliente(0)).getNomeAnimal());
```

Comment: Thanks but just one question. ((Estimacao) clientes.get(0).getAnimaisCliente(0)) what it does its to cast Animal to Estimacao?

Comment: Yes, that means is one animal is not an Estimacao, it will fail (ClassCastException) - you should really check it before you cast with an instanceof

Comment: `Estimacao extends Animal`, so you can downcast `Animal` to `Estimacao`. Not sure that I've got your question

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast your `Animal` to `Estimacao`. But obviously, if you don't want to risk an exception, make sure your `Animal` is of the right class before:

```
Animal animal = clientes.get(0).getAnimaisCliente(0);
if (animal instanceof Estimacao) {
    System.out.println(" Nome: " + ((Estimacao) animal).getNomeAnimal());
}
```

Comment: Great. Now I know a way to control this kind of possible exception

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way: an instance of a subclass is also an instance of the superclass. But an instance of the superclass is not necessarily an instance of the subclass. Thus the superclass methods are always available in both, but the subclass methods are only available in the subclass.

If you are sure you have an instance of the subclass, you can cast it explicitly and call the subclass-specific method on it, but you need to take care in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers provided above, you may want to just consider the general design of your classes. If the `nomeAnimal` is something that the `Animal` class should really be aware of then it might make sense to push it up (even the name of the variable suggests its `Animal`-ness).

If not, then you may want to further consider leveraging polymorphism by adding a displaySpecificInfo() to the `Animal` class and either making it `abstract`, or adding an empty implementation in the `Animal` class. That would allow you to call it from where your current - failing - print call is, and then have the current line in the derived class's implementation. This would save the need for the cast (not that there's anything wrong with casting), as well as create a more OO/Encapsulation-compliant implementation.

Edit:

Excellent note by @Guillaume and my apologies for potentially peeling back more layers of the OO onion then you are interested in!  :)

Comment: +1, agreed, but I think he wants to get the basics first :) I was also about to suggest using composition instead of inheritance, but that's a bit out of scope

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `Animal` to a `Estimacao` to access the methods defined in `Estimacao`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly as you are asking. However, you could add `getNomeAnimal()` in your base class (`Animal`), that would return `null` or an empty string - then the instances which are of `Estimacao` class will return the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a misplaces usage in your animal class:

```
this.animaisCliente[indice] // animaisCliente is not an attribute of Animal
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it unless you cast the Animal type object to Estimacao type. Only after the cast, the getNomeAnimal() will be available to you. But this is a bad thing to do. If your array contains a mix of Animal type and Estimacao type objects then it will fail with ClassCastException.

Comment: Not necessarily bad, when you know what you're doing - but you should definitely check it before you cast. And anyway, usually having to cast indicates a bad design, so it might be necessary to revisit it completely

Comment: I completely agree. But, you can have an array of Estimacao objects instead of Animal when if you for sure know you would never have other subtypes objects in your array. But, I agree that the current implementation needs to be completely visited.

Comment: When I said "when you know what you're doing", I meant when you check the correct class (using instanceof or isAssignableFrom) before each cast